# Lenis smooth scrolling (GSAP) does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

When I enable gsap's smooth scrolling, there is a delay in scrolling on the site. This issue is only resolved when I access the browser settings to deactivate smooth scrolling `chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling`. I want smooth scrolling to function properly without having to go into the browser settings and disable it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const LocomotiveScroll = (await import("locomotive-scroll")).default;
      const locomotiveScroll = new LocomotiveScroll();
    })();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
```

Comment: I'm using NextJS with typescript